# The distribution law of $S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n/3^n$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am a beginner in probability theory.
I have trouble with the following problem.

> Suppose $X_n$ are i.i.d. such that $X_n$ takes $0,2$
>   with $P(X_n=0) = P(X_n=2) =1/2$. 
>   What is the distribution law of $S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n/3^n$?

I was able to show that  $S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n/3^n$ converges almost surely using Kolomolgorov's Three Series Theorem.

But I do not know how to approach identifying the distribution of $S$.
Given $X_n$ i.i.d. Bernoulli I have a sense that I should use DeMoivre Laplace Theorem. 
Any hint or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $S$ is actually the ternary representation of Cantor set. So distribution of $S$ is the uniform distribution on Cantor set in $[0,1]$.